# How get nested json value from the following table in aws athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Here is our code

```
SELECT "count"(*) "count"
    , "httprequest"."country"
    , "httprequest"."headers"
FROM waf_logs_17
WHERE ("httprequest"."uri" LIKE '/login')
GROUP BY "httprequest"."clientip", "httprequest"."country","httprequest"."headers"
ORDER BY "count" limit 5
```

Result is as follow

| count | Country | headers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | [{name=Host, value=app.onlinecheckwriter.com}, {name=X-Forwarded-For, value=75.113.195.00}, {name=X-Forwarded-Proto, value=https}] |

Now question is how we can select the value of X-Forwarded-For  under "httprequest"."headers"

Comment: That is not a json. What is the result of `select typeof("httprequest"."headers") FROM waf_logs_17` ?

Comment: array(row(name varchar, value varchar))

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not json, but array of rows, so you can process it using [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (headers) AS (
    values (array[cast(row('X-Forwarded-For', '75.113.195.00') as ROW(name varchar, value varchar))] )
)

-- query
select 
    reduce(headers, NULL, (v, curr) -> if(curr.name = 'X-Forwarded-For', curr.value, v), v -> v)
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 75.113.195.00 |

Comment: Could you please guide me how can I do group by using  x-forwarded-for-id . SELECT "count"(*) "count"
    , "httprequest"."country"
    , "httprequest"."headers"
FROM waf_logs_17
WHERE ("httprequest"."uri" LIKE '/login')
GROUP BY "httprequest"."clientip", "httprequest"."country","httprequest"."headers"
ORDER BY "count" limit 5

Comment: @jewelhuq perform subselect.

Comment: Need your guidence don't know how can we do it. Actually I am trying to find of from which ip address we were getting more hits. Earielr clientip used to work now after setting up firewall on top it comes as  'X-Forwarded-For instead of client IP